# Re-assigning a name to itself

Tags: python

Notice [these lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc3fa204d357be5fafc10eb8c2a80fe0bca998f1/Lib/multiprocessing/dummy/__init__.py#L91-L92) in `multiprocessing` package of standard libraries:

```
dict = dict
list = list
```

What's the point of rebinding some names already available on `__builtins__` into the module scope?  What is it trying to achieve?  I searched for an explanation in the git blame, but this commit was large and there was no relevant comment.

Comment: I followed the Subversion annotations back on the old repository, but [apparently those lines have been there since the original `multiprocessing` commit](https://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/4511ecd25634/Lib/multiprocessing/dummy/__init__.py#l115).

Comment: wait no that's mercurial not subversion

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This code occurs in `multiprocessing.dummy`, a "fake" version of `multiprocessing` that implements the functionality with threads. If you look down a few lines, you'll see

```
def Manager():
    return sys.modules[__name__]
```

`multiprocessing.dummy` implements `Manager` as a function that just returns the `multiprocessing.dummy` module itself, so the `multiprocessing.dummy` module object has to provide the API of a multiprocessing Manager object. The lines

```
dict = dict
list = list
```

copy the bindings for the `dict` and `list` names from the builtins namespace into the module's namespace, so you can do

```
m = multiprocessing.dummy.Manager()
d = m.dict()
```

as if you had a real `multiprocessing.Manager()`.

Comment: As someone unfamiliar with python; out of curiosity, does this mean that the left side of `dict = dict` refers to a different location/variable than the right side?

Comment: @Rob: Sort of. Global variable lookup falls back to the builtins if it doesn't find a global, as happens on the right side. Global variable assignment always assigns to (module-)globals, though. Thus, this assignment takes the value of `dict` from the built-ins and assigns it to a module-global variable with the same name.

Comment: So, your answer to Rob's question is correct, but no need to say "sort of" — "yes", they are different names.